# MySQL error with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My PHP code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (name, content, in_nav, use_page, page, id) VALUES (?, ?, '$in_nav', '$use_page', ?, '$id'); ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=?, content=?, in_nav='$in_nav', use_page='$use_page', page=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $body, $page, $name, $body, $page);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

But if I execute it, it says:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\cms.php on line 199

When I try `$mysqli->error;` it says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=?, content=?, in_nav='1', use_page='0', page=?' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semi-colon after the `)` that should fix it

Code should be this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (name, content, in_nav, use_page, page, id) VALUES (?, ?, '$in_nav', '$use_page', ?, '$id') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=?, content=?, in_nav='$in_nav', use_page='$use_page', page=?");
```

Answer (score 1):

you have left a semicolon before `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you should remove it.

**Correct syntax** (see [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

**Solution to your problem**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (name, content, in_nav, use_page, page, id) VALUES (?, ?, '$in_nav', '$use_page', ?, '$id') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=?, content=?, in_nav='$in_nav', use_page='$use_page', page=?");
```

hope this helps :-)